# Definition of direct limit of groups by Serre

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, limits-colimits

I've started to read the book Trees by Jean Pierre-Serre, and in Its first section he defines the direct limit of groups. I'm pretty used to the canon definition of direct limits which requires a directed set of indexes $I$ and a set of morphisms satisfying certain conditions (see for example [this](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/DirectLimits.pdf)). The Serre's definition (see below) does not need a directed (nor even an ordered) set of indexes, and it usually appears as a consequence of the definition I know (at least in the basics of group theory, because I know that that actually comes from a more general notion in category thoery). What I really can't handle is his construction  which is based on generators and relations.

I would really appreciate any ideas that could help me to understand that construction and why (if) it is equivalent to the usual one.
[image: Serre's definition]
[image: Construction]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to see how this definition relates to definition you are familiar with, and you also want to know why the described presentation works?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Exactly! I couldn't have said it better

Comment: Are you familiar with the more general notion of colimits?  What's being described here is (basically) a general colimit, rather than the special kind that is commonly called a "direct limit".

Comment: Think about colimits in terms of coequalisers of coproducts.